# How to create an upward triangle with repeat function

Tags: c, arrays, string, function, character

I am trying to create an upward triangle function that utilizes a function that I have already completed that takes a character and prints it however many times you want to.

I want to be clear up front, this is for a homework assignment. I am running into some walls, and just need a little guidance.

Upward triangle Example:

```
*
**
***
****
```

I know how to create an upward triangle function without another function:

```
void utri( int tricount )
{
    int uptri, x;
    char star;
    star = '*';
    for ( uptri = 1; uptri <= tricount; uptri++ )
    {
        for ( x = 0; x < uptri; x++ )
        {
                printf ("%c", star);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

but I am having trouble coming up with a logical way to do so. I am trying to create an upward triangle that will utilize my repeat function below.

This is the repeat function I want to utilize to create my upward triangle function:

```
void rept( int alot, char sym )
{
    int z;

    for ( z = 0; z < alot; z++ )
        printf("%c", sym);

    printf("\n");
}
```

When testing the output, this is the call I want to use:

```
utri(4);
```

Comment: Replace the inner `for` loop with `rept(uptri , star);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is replace the inner `for` loop with the new function you must use, and pass the correct variables to the function by putting them in the function call accordingly, such as: `rept(uptri, star);`.

`uptri` is passed to `rept()` and is the variable named `int alot` (the number of times the loop will run) in that scope, and `star` is the character `char` that will print in `rept()` and is the variable named `char sym` in `rept`'s scope. If you're new to computer programming, "scope" just refers to what part of the program that variable can be seen. So, `rept` can't see the variables `uptri` and `star` until they are passed to it by their value using the function call `rept(uptri, star);`. Once that happens, `rept` uses those variables and assigns their values to the variables in its own scope: `alot` and `sym`.

#### Code

```
void utri( int tricount )
{
    int uptri, x;
    char star;
    star = '*';
    for ( uptri = 1; uptri <= tricount; uptri++ )
    {
        rept(uptri, star);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I suppose since I am still getting used to arrays and functions, I am probably making them way harder for myself than I should be.

Comment: @RobotSpirits No problem! I remember when I was first learning to code with C, the concept of how variables are passed to functions was confusing to me as well, for some reason. I'd appreciate it if you marked my answer as the best answer or one of the other answers if it answered your question in a better way. Cheers.

Comment: You got it! Yeah it's still confusing to me. Unfortunately I have another assignment due very soon with multiple functions and I am completely lost :/ I wish there was more options.

Comment: To summarize again, to use the variables in the function you have to pass them to the function with a function call. In this case it's `rept(uptri, star)`. `uptri` must be an int variable type, and `star` a char type, because the function is declared as `void rept(int alot, char sym)`. When `rept()` runs, `alot` and `sym` hold the data of `uptri` and `star`, respectively. The code in the function runs, and when it reaches the end the program starts where it left off after the function call. In your case, `rept(uptri, star)` runs each time the for loop loops in the `utri()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Congratulations. Your solution works perfectly in seperation. You just have to merge them together to make things work. So your `rept` function prints character `sym` `alot` times and you need to print `star` 1 time for line 1, 2 times for line 2 and so on.. What if we call `rept` passing line number as `alot` and `star` as `sym`?

**See the Code below after thinking a bit about the question.

```
void utri( int tricount )
{
        int uptri, x;
        char star;
        star = '*';
        for ( uptri = 1; uptri <= tricount; uptri++ )
        {
                rept(uptri, star);
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice, it came in handy and was very easy to comprehend.